# Calling a function from function pointer in struct

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers, libcurl

I want to write a wrapper for the callback function for progress information of libcurl in C.
This wrapper should calculate some data which are supposed to be encapsulated in a library.

Here's a description of the basic idea: (I hope this clarifies things)

The user should implement a callback function xFunc and initialize a data structure to store data for the callback function (called xData). Then he should call a wrapper function aFunc. As argument he provides some connection related data and a pointer to xFunc and xData. In aFunc some things are calculated which are required to call a second function bFunc. The xFunc and xData pointer are also passed to this function. In this function, a second data structure YData is initialized. This structure holds a pointer to the user provided xFunc and xData and some other data which are required for calculations. Now the libcurl related things get initialized. As a callback for the upload progress, a second callback function yFunc is implemented in the library. In this function the user provided xFunc should be called with xData and other calculated values.

Now here's the code of my current implementation (I stripped all the calculation code and renamed the functions and structures to math the description above so it looks a bit strange. I hope it isn't too abstract now):

*main.c*

```
int xFunc(void *xData, long int param1, long int param2) {
    //do something with the data
    return 0;
}

int main(void){

    xpData *xData;
    xData->value = 0;

    aFunc(xFunc, p);

    return 0;
}
```

*curlutils.h*

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
} xpData;

int xFunc(void *xData, long int param1, long int param2);
int aFunc(int (*xFunc)(void*, long int, long int), void xData);
int bFunc(int (*xFunc)(void*, long int, long int), void xData);
```

*curlutils.c*

```
typedef struct {
    int (*xFunc)(void*, long int, long int);
    void *data;    
} ypData;


int yFunc(void *p, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow){
    ypData *pd;
    pd = (ypData*) p;    
    return pd->xFunc(pd->data);
}

int bFunc(int (*xFunc)(void*, long int, long int), void xData){
    CURL *curl;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){ //stripped many curl initialization stuff
        ypData *yData;
        yData->data = xData;
        yData->xFunc = xFunc;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, yFunc);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, &yData);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}

int aFunc(int (*xFunc)(void*, long int, long int), void *xData){
    //calculate something useful
    bFunc(xFunc, xData);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in yFunc where I want to call xFunc. The program crashes with the error:

```
Illegal instruction
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: I can't imagine that this is your real code. `void xData` is not a valid parameter to a function, `bfunc` and `bFunc` are not the same identifier, and your `xFunc` parameter to `bFunc` is not even used. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code according to your critics. My real code is a bit messy and not to easy to understand so is abstracted it here.

Comment: As always MAKE SURE TO TURN ON ALL COMPILER WARNINGS (use `-Wall`) and take the time to understand what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you pass pointers as void pointers, you don't get any warnings if you pass the wrong kind of pointer.  Then when you cast the pointer, you cast it to the wrong type and probably jump off to an invalid address.

You have:

```
    ypData *yData;
    yData->data = xData;
    yData->xFunc = xFunc;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, yFunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, &yData);
```

This declares a locat pointer var `yData` but doesn't initialize it.  You then promptly dereference the pointer, which will likely crash (and should give a compile time warning).  If it doesn't, you then pass `&yData` (which is a `ypData **`) to `yFunc` (indirectly via `curl_easy_setopt`), which is expecting a `ypData *` as its argument.

You might be able to fix it by using:

```
    ypData yData;
    yData.data = xData;
    yData.xFunc = xFunc;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, yFunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, &yData);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

this has the potential danger if one of the `curl` functions stash away the pointer to `yData` and a later `curl` call tries to call `yFunc` after this function has returned (and the pointer is dangling).  If that can happen, you need something like:

```
    ypData *yData = malloc(sizeof *yData);
    yData->data = xData;
    yData->xFunc = xFunc;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, yFunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, yData);
```

which has the problem that you don't know when to free the allocated `yData`, so is subject to memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. :) It's strange that the compiler doesn't show me a warning even with -Wall...